# java renameTo method not working

Tags: java, file-rename

I know this has been probably answered a million times on here but everything I have looked at has not helped me.  Here is my code:

```
for(File g: f.listFiles()){
    for(File h : g.listFiles()){
        try{
            Scanner s = new Scanner(h);
            String timestamp = s.next().split("[?]")[4];
            File z = new File(h.getAbsolutePath().split("[.]")[0] + timestamp + h.getAbsolutePath().split("[.]")[1]);
            boolean q = h.renameTo(z);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

I have checked to see if File z exists and it doesnt.  I have checked if File h exists and it does.  I have doublechecked that h is an absolute path.  If I print the absolute path of z, I get the correct path.  None of the directories in f or files in g are open.  The files denoted by h are not open.  Could there be some flag set or something on the file where windows is not allowing my program to rename it?

Comment: This could easily be a permissions issue. Is an exception thrown, or does `renameTo()` just return `false`?

Comment: If z doesn't exists, than maybe your string inside the new File() is not correct, I can't tell what all the splits are for, since I don't know how files are named. what's the output when you just println() everything inside the parenthesis of the Filz z = new File(...)?

Also, add in the catch block e.printStackTrace(); It can enlighten your problem

Comment: No exceptions are thrown.  False is returned

Comment: All I am trying to do is add a timestamp to the names of a bunch of files in a directory.  For instance if I have a.txt, I want it to be a_13345565643.txt.  The timestamp I am getting from within the file

Comment: try to hardcode a path to the renamed files (i bet your path is incorrect with all this splits), maybe add a timestamp to the end of the hardcoded path and test it it works

Comment: Is it possible that h is opened in another filestream or open outside the application

Comment: The problem was that I never closed off the scanner.  So my own program had the file open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are having a similar problem to one I had here [File deletion/moving failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714893/file-deletion-moving-failing)

Try using FileinputStreams for the Scanner

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(h);
fin.open()
Scanner s = new Scanner(fin);
//do work
fin.close()
```

and closing the stream before renaming

Comment: ahhh yes! thank you.  I completely forgot I was opening the file with the scanner and it cant be renamed because its open within my program.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of renameTo varies from platform to platform. Operations that succeed on one platform may fail on another. For example, on my local development workstation (OS X), everything worked as expected. On a production system (Solaris), renameTo failed consistently. I finally determined that it failed when the files were located on different partitions. Obviously that is not the case here, but it illustrates that the method can behave in unexpected ways.

To get consistent behavior, copy the data to a new file, then delete the original.

Answer (score 1):

I had a almost same issue. Some of rename cases succeeded, some failed. For those failed cases, I found, the source file path and destination file path are not on in same file system. In my cases, the NTFS mounted another file system which the destination file would be moved to. Since the rename function's original purpose simply rename a name, not to move the data of the concerned file. If both source file path and destination file path are in different file system, some version of JVM will fail on certain platforms. Actually, it is a bug in java.io and Solaris has fixed this bug in new versions.
Good Luck!

HappyForever,

Comment: This was immensely helpful.  Turns out our issue was that we were trying to renameTo() between different mount points on our Unix server.  Moving the target directory onto the same partition allowed the renameTo() to work as expected.